# MSP430 programming under Linux - mspdebug fails to connect to programmer

Tags: msp430

I am trying to program the MSP430 (on an [MSP-EXP430F5438](http://www.ti.com/tool/msp-exp430f5438) evaluation board) under Linux using gcc-msp430 (I eventually will do code larger than the 16k that the free version of the Code Composer allows).

As a debugger, it is recommended to use [mspdebug](http://mspdebug.sourceforge.net/), but when I try to use it, it doesn't connect to the FET430UIF.

```
~$ sudo mspdebug uif
MSPDebug version 0.19 - debugging tool for MSP430 MCUs
Copyright (C) 2009-2012 Daniel Beer <dlbeer@gmail.com>
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.

TI3410 device is in boot config, setting active
Initializing FET...
FET protocol version is 20408002
Configured for Spy-Bi-Wire
ti3410: usb_bulk_read: No error
warning: fet: set VCC failed
ti3410: can't send data: No such device
fet: command C_IDENT1 failed
fet: identify failed
Trying again...
Initializing FET...
ti3410: can't send data: No such device
fet: open failed
ti3410: warning: TI_CLOSE_PORT failed: No such device
```

The same device works correctly with Code Composer running on a Windows virtual machine or on a physical Windows system, so I know it is working.

I tried on Ubuntu 12.04 and on Arch Linux and got the same errors.

As recommended in an answer, I tried with `-d` and got further, but didn't work:

```
~$ sudo mspdebug uif -d /dev/ttyUSB0
[sudo] password for renan: 
MSPDebug version 0.19 - debugging tool for MSP430 MCUs
Copyright (C) 2009-2012 Daniel Beer <dlbeer@gmail.com>
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.

Trying to open UIF on /dev/ttyUSB0...
Initializing FET...
FET protocol version is 20408002
Configured for Spy-Bi-Wire
Set Vcc: 3000 mV
Device ID: 0x0580
Device: MSP430F5438A
Code memory starts at 0x5c00
Number of breakpoints: 8

uif: read error: Connection timed out
fet: warning: message C_IDENT3 failed
uif: read error: Connection timed out
fet: message C_IDENT2 failed
fet: identify failed
Trying again...
Initializing FET...
uif: read error: Connection timed out
fet: open failed
```

What is wrong?

Comment: I think this is the most suitable SE for this question, but I'm not sure, feel free to migrate it anywhere else if suitable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This mail thread](http://www.mail-archive.com/mspgcc-users@lists.sourceforge.net/msg11217.html) suggests that you need to specify the `-d` option like this:

```
$ sudo mspdebug uif -d /dev/ttyUSB0
```

They state that this is necessary for FET firmware 2.04.09.001 but not necessary for 2.04.05.003.

Your firmware is version 2.04.08.002. So this issue may affect you or it may not.

Comment: It gets slightly farther, but still doesn't work. I added the output to my question

Comment: @Renan Are you connecting through JTAG? If so you need the `-j` option as well. Otherwise try upgrading to the latest release of `mspdebug`. There are some changes to `MSP430.DLL` (a.k.a `tilib`) but I'm not sure what version they were rolled into.

Comment: I tried with `-j`, and did not work too. Will try upgrading

Comment: Well, eventually it started working. (Don't know why). Marking this as the answer, since I needed `-d` and `-j` parameters.